# how to slide the lastview to firstview in viewfillper in android programatically?

Tags: android, view

I am using ViewFillper in my activity. it contained 4 views. My Task is when i lunch the Activity
it should Slide from left to right like First 4 view,next 3 view,next 2 view next 1 view,IN 1 View slide stop here.

This completed functionality i need write in oncreate() only.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already? A little source code might help a lot too.

Comment: my problem sloved,i am using viewfillper.startFlipping(); method